# Biblatex: printing a bibliography twice with different styles

Tags: biblatex

As the title says, I need to print a bibliography twice. I already finished the paper and cited everything using biblatex.

I basically need a bibliography with numerical style and after that another bibliography with all the entries listed in alphabetical order without the numbers, but rather the "verbose" style.

Is there any way to do this? As I understand it I need to specify bibstyle when I include the biblatex package.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is not possible to switch citation or bibliography styles mid-document. But in many cases there are workarounds to achieve the desired effect.

Leaving aside the `dashed` option, there aren't many code differences between a `numeric` bibliography and a `verbose`-style bibliography (which is ultimately just an `authortitle` bibliography). The biggest difference is the bibliography environment and the name format for `sortname`. We just copy the relevant bits from `authortitle.bbx`.

The more interesting problem is sorting. Sorting is usually taken care of by so-called `refcontext`s. If you change the sorting you switch to a different `refcontext`. Sorting isn't the only thing controlled by a `refcontext`, so that switch may affect other details as well (in particular it may change disambiguation calculations). This should not be a concern in this setup, but could be in a different context. For us it is enough to tell `biblatex` explicitly to use `sorting=none,` in citations with `\assignrefcontextentries[sorting=none]{*}`. (That is necessary because `biblatex` usually uses the last `refcontext` an entry was used in for citations. In our case that would be the second author-title bibliography, which has the wrong sort order.)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\assignrefcontextentries[sorting=none]{*}

\newcommand*{\InitializeAuthorTitleBibliography}{%
  \setlength{\bibitemsep}{0pt}%
  \DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}%
  \DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}%
  \DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}%
  \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}%
  \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}%
  \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}}

\defbibenvironment{authotitlebib}
  {\InitializeAuthorTitleBibliography
   \list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman}
dolor \autocite{nussbaum}
ipsum \autocite{geer}
amet \autocite{sigfridsson,aksin,herrmann}

\printbibliography

\newrefcontext[sorting=nty]
\printbibliography[env=authotitlebib, title={Author-Title \refname}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Numeric citations, numeric bibliography, author-title bibliography.]

Comment: Thank you for your effort, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Nico If the answer helped you solve you problem, please consider accepting it to mark the question as resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers